# Installation of Angular fails on macOS High Sierra

Tags: angular, macos, installation

I want to install Angular on the latest macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.15).

The Error output is as follows:

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents
>   node install
>   @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
>   node ./bin/ng-update-message.js
>     sh: node: command not found
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 install: node install
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn ENOENT
>   npm ERR! file sh
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>   npm ERR! syscall spawn
>   npm ERR! @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall: node ./bin/ng-update-message.js
>   npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

**Troubleshoots, which I've done:**
- Restart computer
- clear npm cache
- Delete and reinstall node and npm
- Check environment vars

So I have every time the same issue.

**My node and npm versions are:**

- node -v --> v8.11.3
- npm -v --> 5.6.0

FYI: If I want to install Angular by bower, then I have a warning that the current os version is not supported yet. This wouldn't be a better solution...

Therefore, I downloaded the Angular-package (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#angular-cli) from GitHub, but in there I can't find any script named "postinstall" unfortunately.

Thank you for some tipps!

If you with a full log, so I would post it (but isn't more helpful).

Comment: It should be `npm install` not `node install`. 
You should really be using the `angular-cli`. To install that you can run `npm install -g angular-cli`

Answer (score 2):

With the parameter '--unsave-perm=true' the installation was successful:

Full command for the solution:
`sudo npm install -g angular-cli --unsafe-perm=true`

Thank you!